# Available In/As

Tags: meaning, prepositions, usage

I have a question about the preposition to use when talking about different versions/varieties of a products:

> [NY Times](http://www.nytimes.com/2002/03/10/magazine/i-d-like-to-buy-the-world-a-shelf-stable-children-s-lactic-drink.html?pagewanted=all):
>   Coke's biggest brand in Japan is no longer Coke Classic. It's a brand called Georgia Coffee, served in a can, *available* ***in*** ***more than 10 varieties***.

How would the meaning change if "*in*":

> ...available ***in*** more than 10 varieties.

is replaced with "*as*":

> ...available ***as*** more than 10 varieties.

?

Comment: It would be grammatically and logically "correct" to use _as_ here, but for decades, hordes of copywriters have standarized on _in._ A much more interesting question is why they write _more than 10 varieties._ Why not just write _available in 13 varieties,_ or whatever is the actual number of varieties?

Comment: I don't think "as" is grammatically correct here at all... it sounds very awkward indeed, not just less common. Logically correct, maybe, but grammatically no. "In" is used for adjectives... you can have something "**in** blue" or "**in** a different style" or, for this example, "**in** every flavor." Why "in" rather than "as"? I don't know, honestly, sometimes preposition choices don't make intuitive sense. They just *are*.

Comment: It's unusual, uncommon, and it's far from the standard ad lingo, but there's nothing "wrong" with offering a drink _as_ a number of varieties. I happily await an analysis which convinces me that this is false.

Answer (score 1):

Prepositions are a tricky thing.

However the standard collocation with **available** is **in** as this [google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=available+as+more%2Cavailable+in+more+&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cavailable%20as%20more%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cavailable%20in%20more%3B%2Cc0) shows.

You can also look at the ways available as is most commonly used [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=available+as+*&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cavailable%20as%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bavailable%20as%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bavailable%20as%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bavailable%20as%20an%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bavailable%20as%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bavailable%20as%20well%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bavailable%20as%20food%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bavailable%20as%20part%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bavailable%20as%20soon%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bavailable%20as%20yet%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bavailable%20as%20of%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Another way to say this: "It comes in more than 10 varieties."